# get dimentions of image while uploading

Tags: javascript, jquery

While browsing and uploading images, I want to know the image's height and width and based on this I want to resize and show it. Can I achieve this with javascript?

I am trying this the following code but its working only in IE, any other solutions please?

```
 img_id++;
 var id="imgid"+img_id;
 image = document.getElementById('submit').value;
 document.getElementById('div').innerHTML="<img id='"+id+"' src='"+image+"' >";
 document.getElementById(id).style.visibility="hidden";
 alert(document.getElementById(id).offsetWidth +'by'+document.getElementById(id).offsetHeight);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't have anything to do with Java right? Removed the tag.

Comment: No this is not possible with pure JavaScript. It can't read the image file from the client machine hard disk, it must be uploaded to the server first.

Comment: @Shadow: HTML5 File API should work.

Comment: @FelixKling oh my.. totally forgot about it!

Answer (score 0):

Why are you assigning 'div' as id? 'div' is a tag in HTML :

```
document.getElementById('div').innerHTML="<img id='"+id+"' src='"+image+"' >";
```

Change it to something else and check if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to maintain the aspect ratio?

Have you tried setting the css like this:

```
$('#theImage').css('height', WHATEVER_SIZE);
$('#theImage').css('width','auto');
```

Probably don't need the auto (which would maintain your aspect ratio)